# Loading an XML file in MVC ASP.NET from a server instead of the local drive path

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, relative-path

I feel like I'm missing some configuration in IIS or Global file maybe ?

I want to load an xml file:

```
var icon = XDocument.Load("/images/body/logos/LogoImageMappings.xml");
```

When running it fails because it tries to locate the file @ C:\images\body\logos\LogoImageMappings.xml

How can I correctly direct it to Localhost ( or web server when published ) application drive instead of a local c: ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to map the path to the directory where the file resides. Use this:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/images/body/logos/LogoImageMappings.xml");
var icon = XDocument.Load(path);
```

The `Server.MapPath` function will map the relative path to the full path of the file on the server, replacing tilde with the right directory (note that the relative path must point to a sub-directory of your web-site directory, for security reasons usually you can't access anything higher than that).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It didnt work unfortunately.  I added screenshot to OP.

Comment: @Shenaniganz Does it work? I do not see any screenshot in the question!

Comment: Ah yes, it finally worked. After struggling for a while I noticed a small typo in my path. Both yours and Anotonio's solutions work. I accepted yours for extra explanation which I found useful and hopefully others will too.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You have virtual path, to get physical path use MapPath :

```
var icon = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/body/logos/LogoImageMappings.xml"));
```

Comment: Thank you. It didn't work unfortunately. I added screenshot above ( let me know if its too small to see )

Comment: could you post how do you set imageIconDirectory ?